# Go to a specific page on a pdf using wx.lib.pdfwin_old

Tags: python, wxpython

It seems that wx.lib.pdfwin_old has functions for going to only the previous and next page for a pdf. How do you modify it to go to a specific page on a pdf or what's the code for going to a specific page on a pdf?

```
import  wx
if wx.Platform == '__WXMSW__':
    from wx.lib.pdfwin_old import PDFWindow

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=-1)
        self.pdf = None

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)


        self.pdf = PDFWindow(self, size=(parent.GetSize().width,parent.GetSize().height*3/5),style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        sizer.Add(self.pdf, proportion=3, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)

        btn = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Open PDF File")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenButton, btn)
        sizer.Add(btn, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnOpenButton(self, event):
        global current_pdf_path
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, wildcard="*.pdf")
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            wx.BeginBusyCursor()
            print(dlg.GetPath())
            self.pdf.LoadFile(dlg.GetPath())
            wx.EndBusyCursor()

        dlg.Destroy()

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "PDFWindow", size = (640, 480))
MyPanel(frame)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
setCurrentPage(n)
```

From pdfwin_old.py:

```
def setCurrentPage(self, npage):
    """
    Goes to the specified page in the document.  Maintains the
    current location within the page and zoom level.  npage is
    the page number of the destination page.  The first page
    in a document is page 0.

    ## Oh no it isn't! The first page is 1 (dfh)
    """
    if self.ie.Document:
        return self.ie.Document.setCurrentPage(npage)
    else:
        raise PDFWindowError()
```

Edit:
Sorry Boikem, can't help! I didn't realise that `pdfwin` was windows only, although the clue is in the name. I run on Linux.
As a consolation, I offer this code below, a method using a browser, which may or may not give you some mileage. (python3)

```
import  wx
import webbrowser

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=-1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        btn = wx.Button(self, wx.NewId(), "Open PDF File")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOpenButton, btn)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnOpenButton(self, event):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, wildcard="*.pdf")
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            url = dlg.GetPath()
        dlg.Destroy()
        try:
            if not url:
                return
        except:
            return
        url = "file://"+url+'#page=12'
        url = url.encode('UTF-8')
        print(url)
        browser_list = ("chromium-browser","firefox")
        for x in browser_list:
            try:
                browser = webbrowser.get(x)
            except:
                pass
            else:
                browser.open(url)
                break
        try:
            if browser:
                pass
        except:
            print("Neither Supported browsers Firefox or Chromium found")

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "PDF Via Browser", size = (640, 480))
MyPanel(frame)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

The `chromium` browser seems to be the most accurate.
Personally, for displaying `help` in my projects, I create a single `main` pdf and breakout of it, content specific pdf's for each topic by using `sections` within the main document. This method avoids issues when the page numbers change, as the documentation develops.
I'd suggest that you un-accept this answer, as it clearly does not answer your specific question.

Comment: But I'm getting a raise PDFWindowError():  A PDF must be loaded before calling this method. I loaded the pdf with self.pdf.LoadFile(dlg.GetPath()) and then called self.pdf.setCurrentPage(3) but still not working.

Comment: It loads the pdf alright  but  calling the setCurrentPage  is what causes the error

Comment: More tests on the code shows that its using self.ie.Navigate2(filename) instead of self.ie.Document.LoadFile(fileName) . This loads pdf files (at least with Foxit but not Adobe) but does not make me able to have features such as going to specific pages. How do you also solve that? Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I think I'll stick to that for now